# Puppy became very thin in a day

Tags: dogs, health, feeding

I feed a litter of stray puppies. A puppy was just healthy enough, but suddenly when I saw him the next day, he became so thin I can see his rib cage. What could have happened and what can I do without a vet?

Comment: How many puppies in the litter?  I assume they all live together.  Do you watch to make sure everyone gets a share, or is it possible the others took his part?

Comment: @JamesJenkins 4. I just feed them some biscuits sir. They eat from the garbage.